# R's hist function running extremely slowly on large data set

Tags: r, histogram

I have a not-so-large (well, "large" is relative) array/vector of 1,224,647 p-values.

The run takes about 15 minutes on my Ubuntu VM.  The long run time troubles me, because this is a small subset of the data that I have to analyze.

I've read through the manual, run search engines, and I don't see anyone else having this problem, which is very puzzling.

my session information:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3
```

my script is very simple:

```
setEPS()
postscript('p_values.histogram.eps')
hist(d, breaks=10, main = 'p values', xlab = 'p')
dev.off()
```

I could write a script that counts each histogram bin, and then make a simplified data set, but that seems too complicated for such a routine task.

What's truly bizarre is that when I run

```
t0 <- proc.time()
source("tmp.R")
t1 <- proc.time()
print(t1-t0)
x100     <- rnorm(100)
x1000    <- rnorm(1000)
x10000   <- rnorm(10000)
x100000  <- rnorm(100000)
x1000000 <- rnorm(1000000)
#
t0 <- proc.time()
hist(x100)
t1 <- proc.time()
print("100")
print(t1-t0)
#-------------
t0 <- proc.time()
hist(x1000)
t1 <- proc.time()
print("1000")
print(t1-t0)
#-------------
t0 <- proc.time()
hist(x10000)
t1 <- proc.time()
print("10000")
print(t1-t0)
#-------------

t0 <- proc.time()
hist(x100000)
t1 <- proc.time()
print("100000")
print(t1-t0)
#-------------
t0 <- proc.time()
hist(x1000000)
t1 <- proc.time()
print("1000000")
print(t1-t0)
pdf("tmp.pdf")
#-------------
t0 <- proc.time()
hist(d)

t1 <- proc.time()
print("d")
dev.off()
print(t1-t0)
```

the `hist` function runs very quickly... but it doesn't in the script.

How can I generate this histogram in a more reasonable time frame in R?  Is there some trick that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I think it shouldn't change anything, but have you tried using a different device, e.g. `pdf`?

Comment: @starja unfortunately, running PDF instead of EPS is also extremely slow.

Comment: can you show us `str(d)` ?  Maybe it's in some weird data structure that is confusing `hist()` ?

Comment: @BenBolker the output of `str(d)
 num [1:1224647] 0.5498 0.423 0.4605 0.0107 0.9394 ...

Comment: OK, it's a boring numeric vector.  How does performance on my test function below scale?  Perhaps you're memory-limited.  (Although a numeric vector of 1e7 is 'only' 76 Mb).  How much other stuff do you have in your environment?

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04 (non-virtual, fairly new laptop) things work a lot better for me.

Here's a test script to time the action of plotting a histogram for a vector of `n` uniformly distributed values:

```
mkhist <- function(n) {
    tt <- system.time({
        set.seed(101)
        x <- runif(n)
        setEPS()
        postscript("tmp.eps")
        hist(x,breaks=10)
        dev.off()
    })
    return(tt)
}
```

<1 second for 10^6:

```
mkhist(1e6)
##   user  system elapsed 
##  0.049   0.016   0.065
```

Scales pretty much linearly up to 100 million (5 seconds):

```
mkhist(1e8)
##    user  system elapsed 
##   5.041   0.668   5.709
```

Comment: this script has the same slowness problem :( I'm running from a text file, will that make a difference?

Comment: How does it scale (e.g. for n=1e3, 1e4, 1e5) ?  What happens if you take out the EPS calls?